# Convert string "0x32" into a single byte

Tags: c#

I'm working with C# trying to convert a string value into a byte. Seems to be harder then I expected. Basically I have a string called hex = "0x32" and need byte block to equal this value.

```
string hex = "0x32";
byte block = Convert.ToByte(hex);
```

The above doesn't work, does anybody know how I can successfully assign the hex value to the byte. I need to append this byte to a byte array later in the code.

Comment: Not an answer, but arrays don't allow appending in c#.  You may want to try a list instead.

Comment: @JaredPar, "I need to append this byte to a byte array later in the code. Thanks!"

Comment: @James, read right past that.

Answer (score 6):

Try the following

```
byte block = Byte.Parse(hex.SubString(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

The reason for the `SubString` call is to remove the preceeding "0x" from the string.  The Parse function does not expect the "0x" prefix even when `NumberStyles.HexNumber` is specified and will error if encountered

Comment: These examples simply convert the hex value into decimal format then assigning the decimal to byte. So 32 = 50 in decimal but the problem is that I have a byte array that needs to send in this format: byte[] cmd = { 0x02, 0x05, 0x01, 0x41, 0x23, 0x10, block, checksum }; block needs to equal 0x32 as a byte based on the value coming in... so if 50 is selected I'm converting it to 0x32 as a string but need to assign it to the byte. It can't be 50 because the wrong command gets sent through the serial port.

Comment: @bl4kh4k: It sounds like your problem isn't with hex conversion then.

Answer (score 2):

```
Convert.ToByte(hex, 16)
```

Comment: These examples simply convert the hex value into decimal format then assigning the decimal to byte. So 32 = 50 in decimal but the problem is that I have a byte array that needs to send in this format:

byte[] cmd = { 0x02, 0x05, 0x01, 0x41, 0x23, 0x10, block, checksum };

block needs to equal 0x32 as a byte based on the value coming in... so if 50 is selected I'm converting it to 0x32 as a string but need to assign it to the byte. It can't be 50 because the wrong command gets sent through the serial port.

Comment: @bl4kh4k A number is a number, no matter what base you represent it in. `byteval = 0x32` does the same thing as `byteval = 50`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    string hex = "0x32";
    int value = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);
    byte byteVal = Convert.ToByte(value);
```

Will work...

**Edit**

A little code to demonstrate that 0x32 (hex) and 50 (int) are the same.

```
    string hex = "0x32";
    byte[] byteVal = new byte[1];
    byteVal[0] = Convert.Byte(hex, 16);
    Console.WriteLine(byteVal[0] + " - Integer value");
    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(byteVal) + " - BitArray representation");;
```

Comment: These examples simply convert the hex value into decimal format then assigning the decimal to byte. So 32 = 50 in decimal but the problem is that I have a byte array that needs to send in this format: byte[] cmd = { 0x02, 0x05, 0x01, 0x41, 0x23, 0x10, block, checksum }; block needs to equal 0x32 as a byte based on the value coming in... so if 50 is selected I'm converting it to 0x32 as a string but need to assign it to the byte. It can't be 50 because the wrong command gets sent through the serial port.

Comment: @bl4kh4k Look at the edited tidbit of code. You'll see the output demonstrates that 50 (int) and 0x32 (hex) are the same, depending on how the value is visualized (by VS 2010 visualizers)